# MSSQL date time overlapping issue for availability and non availabiliy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need to find overlapped records in MS-SQL, at the time of insert DateFrom, DateTo, SatrtTime, EndTime.

Suppose I am scheduling teacher lecture period for FromDate to EndDate on specific start time and end time.

Need to overcome from following scenario where last two records are overlapped

```
╔═════════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║   DateFrom;     ║     DateTo;    ║    IsFullDay;    ║     StartTime;       ║       EndTime;     ║
║     {Date};     ║     {Date};    ║     {Bit};       ║      {Time(7)};      ║      {Time(7)};    ║
╠═════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2015-10-10;     ║ 2015-10-17;    ║               0; ║     13:00;           ║      14:45;        ║ **Inserted**  ║
║ 2015-10-16;     ║ 2015-10-18;    ║               0; ║     14:00;           ║      14:15;        ║ **Overlapped**║
║ 2015-10-11;     ║ 2015-10-11;    ║               1; ║     00:00;           ║      00:00;        ║ **Overlapped**║
╚═════════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════════╩════════════════════╝═══════════════╝
```

Please suggest for MSSQL procedure changes.

Comment: What does your `insert` statement look like?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately MS SQL doesn't have range type you need to check yourself. It would be wise to have Start and End as DateTime values instead of separate Date and Time values as you did. Assuming you haqd them as DateTime instead:

```
declare @Start DateTime = '2015/10/16 14:00';
declare @endDate DateTime = '2015/10/18 14:15';

select count(*) from myTable where @endDate > DateFrom and @Start < DateTo;
```

If result is not 0 then you have overlap(s).

Comment: Unfortunately I have such tpe of DB design,
and wants to find minimum efforts solution without disturbing this design.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert select with the overlapping condition:

```
INSERT MyTable (DateFrom, DateTo, IsFullDay, StartTime, EndTime)
SELECT MyDateFrom, MyDateTo, MyIsFullDay, MyStartTime, MyEndTime
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable mt2
               WHERE (MyDateTo > mt2.DateFrom and MyDateTo <= mt2.DateTo) or
                     (mt2.DateTo > MyDateFrom and mt2.DateTo <= MyDateTo))
```

Comment: Instead of MyTable use your table name which was not specified in the question, instead of MyDateFrom and MyDateTo, respectively, use the dates you have. Apart from that, the query should be self-explanatory: you are selecting the values you need to insert if and only if they fulfill your expectations implemented in the inner select and the result will be the set of rows to be inserted. This set will be used by the insert.

Answer (score 1):

(I would add this add a comment but it didn't let me to put the code there)

Then convert the values to get them as datetime (Since you would this many times, I think you would want to create it as a function):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    myTable
WHERE   @endDate > CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateFrom, 111) + ' ' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartTime, 114) AS DATETIME) AND
        @Start < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTo, 111) + ' ' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EndTime, 114) AS DATETIME);
```

Edit: BTW I am not giving samples in the context of an insert, because if you are doing a scheduling application, then you would need all sorts of this check.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Cetin Basoz And @Lajos Arpad for your suggestions, I have tried your suggested solutions, but possible I'm making some mistakes to implement.

BTW My project Architect allow me to Add another detail table in which need to insert each day with start end time so my new time table is like

Master Table AvailabilityDate
╔══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═══════╗

║LectureId ║  DateFrom  ║DateTo     ║IsFullDay  ║StartTime║EndTime║

║10512     ║  2015-10-14║2015-10-17 ║1          ║11:00    ║11:30  ║

║10513     ║  2015-10-12║2015-10-14 ║0          ║11:00    ║12:30  ║

╚══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═══════╝

Here ISFullDay means full day availability

Detail Table AvailabilityTime
╔══════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗

║LectureId ║StartDateTime       ║EndDateTime        ║

║10512     ║2015-10-14 00:00:00 ║2015-10-14 23:59:59║

║10512     ║2015-10-15 00:00:00 ║2015-10-14 23:59:59║

║10512     ║2015-10-16 00:00:00 ║2015-10-14 23:59:59║

║10512     ║2015-10-17 00:00:00 ║2015-10-14 23:59:59║

║10513     ║2015-10-12 11:00:00 ║2015-10-12 12:30:00║

║10513     ║2015-10-13 11:00:00 ║2015-10-13 12:30:00║

║10513     ║2015-10-14 11:00:00 ║2015-10-14 12:30:00║

╚══════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝

And Procedure Changes are as follows
DECLARE @DetailDateTime TABLE(StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)
DECLARE @EndDateTable NVARCHAR(10)= @EndTime

IF(@IsFullDay = 1)
BEGIN
SET @StartTime = '00:00'
SET @EndDateTable= '00:00'
SET @EndTime =  '23:59:59:900'  --When not dependent on @IsFullDay replace this value
END
--IF(@DateFrom < @DateTo)       -- When no value required in time table if From and To Date are same uncomment this
BEGIN
    ;WITH DetailDateTime As
    (
    SELECT 1 AS COUNTER, @DateFrom AS DateFrom, @DateFrom AS DateTo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNTER + 1, DATEADD(DAY,COUNTER,@DateFrom), DATEADD(DAY,COUNTER,@DateFrom)
    FROM DetailDateTime
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, COUNTER, @DateFrom) <= @DateTo
    )
    INSERT INTO @DetailDateTime SELECT DateFrom+@StartTime StartTime,DateTo+@EndTime FROM DetailDateTime

IF(NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
    [dbo].AvailabilityTime A WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].AvailabilityDates D WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.LectureId = D.LectureId AND ISNULL(D.ISDELETED,0) = 0
    INNER JOIN @DetailDateTime B ON (A.StartTime < B.EndDate) AND (B.StartDate < A.EndTime) AND A.AvailabiliyId <> @AvailabiliyId
    ))
BEGIN
    IF(@AvailabiliyId = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].AvailabilityDate ...
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Update  [dbo].AvailabilityDate ... WHERE A.AvailabiliyId = @AvailabiliyId
        DELETE FROM [dbo].AvailabilityTime WHERE NonAvailabiliyId = @NonAvailabiliyId
    END
    INSERT INTO  [dbo].AvailabilityTime SELECT @NonAvailabiliyId,* FROM @DetailDateTime
END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @AvailabiliyId = -1 -- Overlapping Conflict
    END

Thanks Alot for spending time for me. 
:)

Please let me know if in this solution, I'll stuck somewhere else

Comment: @Ragul 
please help me to format table I tried but not like you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately your design doesn't make sense to me.